# SQL schema, three relations only between two tables, can I do that?

Tags: sql, schema, database-relations

I have two tables, `login_inf` (information about login) and `history` (history of changes in database, for example which user edited specified row) - picture below:

[image]

I want to know which user did a specified action, which user added a row (`created_by`), which user edited a row (`modified_by`) and which user deleted a row (`removed_by`). Is my schema correct?

Relations:

```
history.created_by <-> login_inf.login

history.modified_by <-> login_inf.login

history.removed_by <-> login_inf.login
```

So these three columns in table history are one column from `login_inf`, I just changed the name.

Comment: Your schema is fine.

Comment: I've seen these multiple references 10 to 12 deep before...you are fine here.

Comment: Thank you for responding :)

Comment: As pointed out by Siyual, having `created_by`, `modified_by` and `removed_by` don't make a whole lot of sense if you are capturing the 'history' at an action level. I assume action being something like inserting, updating, or deleting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema looks ok. Keep in mind that you will need to enforce insertion into your `history` table via triggers or code, and this can bog down your database heavily if you have a lot of changes. Your `history` table can also grow very large.

Comment: Thank you for responding :) I have triggers for generate rows in my table `history` and I know that it will slow down my database. I think that this table will be clean up after few months, because data in this table won't be useful anymore :)